# Unexpected function, which exists, when trying to instantiate class

Tags: php

So I've got a simple class here:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    private $key;
    private $location;

    function __construct($par1Key, $par2Location)
    {
        if(empty($par1Key) || empty($par2Location))
            throw new Exception("One or more parameters were left empty.");
        //do stuff
    }

    public static function new($par1Key, $par2Location) {
        try {
            return new MyClass($par1Key, $par2Location);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now I'm trying to do this when I require it in my projects page:

```
<?php
    require('myclass.php');

    function getInfo($location) {
        $key = 'xyzabc123';
        $class = MyClass::new($key, $location);

        return $class->myMethod();
    }
?>
```

But it throws the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in
>   PATHTOFILE/file.php on line 6.

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: I think that `new` is a reserved keyword, you can't use it as a function name.

Comment: if my answer helped, check it as accepted so others can see it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` is one of the [reserved keywords](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/reserved.keywords.php) in PHP, you cannot use it as a function or variable name.

[image]

Change your function name to something else, like `createNew` or something and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Philter Fernandes, the issue was pointed out that `new` is a reserved keyword. I changed the method name and it works now.